# Sitecore powershell search all the items which contain the keyword

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-mvc

I'm completely new to **sitecore powershell**. I have gone through some articles but nothing worked for me.

What I need is: in my Sitecore, I want to search for a specific keyword, and I want all the items listed in the output. The keyword may be contained in Single-Line text, Multiline Text, General Link, RichText or Image. I know this is achievable using **sitecore powershell**. Could any genius (of course for me they are)  solve my problem?

Something I was trying  out. If this is not making any sense, please ignore :)

```
cd 'master:/sitecore/content'
 
function FilterItemsToProcess($item) 
{
    Get-Item master:\content
}
 
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$itemsToProcess = Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | foreach {FilterItemsToProcess($_)}
if($itemsToProcess -ne $null)
{
     
    $itemsToProcess | ForEach-Object { 
        $match = 0;
        foreach($field in $_.Fields) {
 
            # Only look within Single-line and Rich Text fields
            # In this example, we look for english content within Chinese versions
             
            if($field.Type -eq "Single-Line Text" -or $field.Type -eq "Rich Text") {
                if($field -match "mykeyword") {
                    Write-Host "Found: '$field' within a" $field.Type "field on Item:" $_.ID
                    $match = 1;
                }
            }
 
        }
        if($match -eq 1){
            [void]$list.Add($_)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You really want to change the approach you have here. What you have is going to perform very badly. To do any kind of searching in Sitecore you want to use `SearchAPI` - if you look at the [`Find-Item`](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Find-Item.html) command in SPE

Also you will want to add a custom computed field to the index to make this simpler.

In the custom field add all fields that are `Single-line text` or `Richtext` to the index:

So in the computed field you could do something like:

```
public class MyCustomField : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var item = (Item)(indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var value = new StringBuilder();
        item.Fields.ReadAll();
        foreach (Field field in item.Fields)
        {
            switch (field.Type.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "single-line text":
                case "richtext":
                    value.AppendLine(field.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return value;

    }
}
```

Then add the field to your config via an include file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <indexConfigurations>
                <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
                    <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                        <field fieldName="mycustomfield">MyProject.ComputedFields.MyCustomField, MyProject</field>
                    </fields>
                </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
            </indexConfigurations>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

So you could change your powershell to:

```
Find-Item `
    -Index sitecore_master_index `
    -Criteria @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content/" }
              @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "mycustomfield"; Value = "mykeyword"}
```

That would then give you all items that have your keyword in the required field types.

An alternative if you can't add the custom field would be:

```
Find-Item `
    -Index sitecore_master_index `
    -Criteria @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content/" }
              @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "_content"; Value = "mykeyword"}
```

This would give you all instances where *any* field in the item contains the value `mykeyword`. Because only `Single-line Text`, `Multi-line text` and `Richtext` store the textual content, that should be pretty close to what you want. You may get some contamination from fields like link fields or image fields if that text is in any of the properties of the field.

Comment: Thanks @Richard for that. But is there any otherway, where i can get that list without code changes. As i have to search in content authoring server.

Comment: There is a field called `_content` - this contains all fields from the item concatenated together. So you could search that one. You just don't have the filter on the field type. I'll update my answer to include that

Comment: Updated the answer to include the option using `_content`